# Unable to emit event when a checkbox is clicked. (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using **web sockets**, where I want to perform an action when the checkbox in my form is clicked. But I am facing some issues i.e. the emit event is not working and the server is not responding.

**Here is my code :**

**1.app.js**

```
 io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    socket.on("approve",(s,callback)=>{
        console.log(s);
        callback();
    })
})
```

**2. index.ejs**

```
<input class="approvedStatus" name="approve" type="checkbox"> //this is the checkbox



<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io();
    $(".approvedStatus").on("click",function(){
        socket.emit("approve",{
            status: 2
        },function(){
            console.log("Data recieved by the server");
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I think you haven't created node server for the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure socket.io is inserted into `index.ejs`:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And socket.io server started in `app.js`:

```
io = ws.listen(server);
```